# syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.' when I run rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run rake db:migrate I got 
syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting tCOLON2 or '[' or '.'
Error.Please help me

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change

    create_table :users do |t|

      t.string, :name

      t.string, :email

      t.string :login


      t.timestamps

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: `'\n'` means newline. is that any help?

Answer (score 10):

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :login
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You have entered , after string type and that is the only syntax error.

Comment: is it solving your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Remove Comma and try to run the migration.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :login

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

> remove unnecessary comma

You might have entered comma during generating model or scaffold

This is what it should look

```
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.string :email
  t.string :login
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: This was my problem - put commas when using `rails generate model`